# Create dyanamic List Row layout Programmatically

Tags: android, listview, layout, dynamic, template-engine

We are looking for a template based solution to list row where each list row might have different-2 field and their alignment which will be driven by server in the form of json.

This json will have information about no of fields and type of fields like Label, image and their alignment

We came up with a solution where for each row, in getView() method, we are parsing layout json and creating field Programmatically and adding corresponding values and then adding this to relative layout and then adding all these relative layout to parent Linear Layout with vertical orientation. then assigning this layout to convertview and this way, row is created.

With this solution list view is not smooth, because lots of calculation is happening to generate dynamic fields.

Below is the code for sample layout json

```
{
  "layouts": [
  {
  "templateId": "HCI",
  "width": "100%",
  "backgroundColor": "#87CEFA",
  "selectedBackgroundColor": "#96F2CD",
  "cornerRadius": "0",
  "borderWidth": "1",
  "borderColor": "#000000",
  "children": [
    {
      "width": "100%",
      "height": "20",
      "rightAlign": "0",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "label",
          "field": "claimantName",
          "textColor": "#EB6208",
          "alignment": "left",
          "fontSize": "16",
          "style": "upper",
          "horizontalPadding": "5",
          "bold": "1"
        },
        {
          "type": "label",
          "field": "workType",
          "textColor": "#EB6208",
          "alignment": "left",
          "fontSize": "16",
          "style": "upper",
          "horizontalPadding": "5",
          "bold": "0"
        },
        {
          "type": "label",
          "field": "workkardNumber",
          "backgroundColor": "#2D5DB9",
          "textColor": "#FFFFFF",
          "alignment": "right",
          "horizontalPadding": "3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "width": "100%",
      "height": "15",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "label",
          "field": "address",
          "textColor": "#458B00",
          "alignment": "left",
          "fontSize": "16",
          "style": "upper",
          "horizontalPadding": "5",
          "bold": "1"
        },
        {
          "type": "label",
          "field": "lossDate",
          "textColor": "#838B83",
          "alignment": "",
          "fontSize": "16",
          "style": "lower",
          "horizontalPadding": "5",
          "bold": "0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "width": "100%",
      "height": "15",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "label",
          "field": "county",
          "textColor": "#838B83",
          "alignment": "left",
          "fontSize": "16",
          "style": "upper",
          "horizontalPadding": "5",
          "bold": "0"
        },
        {
          "type": "label",
          "field": "zip",
          "textColor": "#0000FF",
          "alignment": "",
          "fontSize": "16",
          "style": "lower",
          "horizontalPadding": "5",
          "bold": "0"
        },
        {
          "type": "label",
          "field": "state",
          "textColor": "#458B00",
          "alignment": "",
          "fontSize": "16",
          "style": "upper",
          "horizontalPadding": "5",
          "bold": "0"
        },
        {
          "type": "label",
          "field": "reportedDate",
          "textColor": "#838B83",
          "alignment": "",
          "fontSize": "16",
          "style": "lower",
          "horizontalPadding": "5",
          "bold": "0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "width": "100%",
      "height": "50",
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "spacer",
          "width": "20"
        },
        {
          "type": "label",
          "field": "lossType",
          "style": "upper",
          "width": "280",
          "textColor": "#458B00",
          "bold": "1",
          "fontSize": "16"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "width": "100%",
      "height": "20",
      "children": [

      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

]
}

And Below is my logic to parse and dynamic field creation

```
public LinearLayout generateLayout(Object object, WorkkardData workkard){
    this.workkardData=workkard;
    JSONObject json = (JSONObject)object;
    String template="";
    String cardBackground="";
    String cardSelectedBackground="";
    ArrayList child=new ArrayList();
    ArrayList subChild=new ArrayList();
    String fieldName="";
    try {
        template = json.getString("templateId");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        cardBackground = json.getString("backgroundColor");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        cardSelectedBackground = json.getString("selectedBackgroundColor");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        cardBackground = json.getString("backgroundColor");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    LinearLayout workkardrowLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    workkardrowLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    workkardrowLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(cardBackground));

    try {
        JSONArray childrentop = json.getJSONArray("children");
        child.add(childrentop);
        for (int i = 0; i < childrentop.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray subChildren = childrentop.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("children");
            subChild.add(subChildren);

            String width="350", height="0", rightAlignmen="0";
            int widthInt=0;
            try {
                width = childrentop.getJSONObject(i).getString("width");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                height = childrentop.getJSONObject(i).getString("height");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                rightAlignmen = childrentop.getJSONObject(i).getString("rightAlign");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(width.equalsIgnoreCase("100%")){
                widthInt = 350;
            }else{
                widthInt = 350*(Integer.parseInt(width.trim().split("%")[0]))/100;
            }

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsll1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(widthInt,Integer.parseInt(height.trim()));
            /*if(rightAlignmen.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                                                                            paramsll1.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
                                                            }else{
                                                                            paramsll1.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

                                                            }*/

            LinearLayout listLayoutRow1 = new LinearLayout(context);
            ll[i] = new LinearLayout(context);
            ll[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            ll[i].setWeightSum(10);
            ll[i].setLayoutParams(paramsll1);

            if(subChildren.length()==0){
                workkardrowLayout.addView(ll[i]);
            }else{
                for (int j = 0; j < subChildren.length(); j++) {

                    String type = "", field= "", backgroundColor ="", textColor ="", alignment ="",horizontalPadding ="", bold="",widthChild="",textColorChild="",fontSize="",style="lower";
                    try {
                        type = subChildren.getJSONObject(j).getString("type");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        field = subChildren.getJSONObject(j).getString("field");
                        fieldName=field;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        backgroundColor = subChildren.getJSONObject(j).getString("backgroundColor");
                        //ll[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(backgroundColor));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        textColor = subChildren.getJSONObject(j).getString("textColor");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        alignment = subChildren.getJSONObject(j).getString("alignment");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        horizontalPadding = subChildren.getJSONObject(j).getString("horizontalPadding");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        bold = subChildren.getJSONObject(j).getString("bold");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        widthChild = subChildren.getJSONObject(j).getString("width");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        textColorChild = subChildren.getJSONObject(j).getString("textColor");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        fontSize = subChildren.getJSONObject(j).getString("fontSize");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        style = subChildren.getJSONObject(j).getString("style");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    int padding=0;
                    try {
                        padding = Integer.parseInt(horizontalPadding);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llChild = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    //paramsll1. = Integer.parseInt(horizontalPadding);
                    //paramsll1.topMargin = 10;
                    //paramsll1.bottomMargin = 10;
                    //paramsll1.rightMargin = 10;
                    //paramsll1.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
                    if(rightAlignmen.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                        llChild.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
                    }

                    if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("label")){
                        TextView listText1 = new TextView(context);
                        if(style.equalsIgnoreCase("upper")){
                            //listText1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                            listText1.setText(this.getWorkkardMethod(field).toUpperCase());
                        }else{
                            listText1.setText(this.getWorkkardMethod(field));
                        }
                        if(field.equalsIgnoreCase("lossDate")){
                            listText1.setText("Loss Date:"+this.getWorkkardMethod(field));
                        }
                        if(field.equalsIgnoreCase("reportedDate")){
                            listText1.setText("Reported:"+this.getWorkkardMethod(field));
                        }
                        if (!backgroundColor.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                            listText1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(backgroundColor));
                        }
                        listText1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(textColor));
                        if (!fontSize.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                            listText1.setTextSize(Integer.parseInt(fontSize));
                        }
                        listText1.setPadding(padding,padding, padding, padding);
                        if(alignment.equalsIgnoreCase("left")){
                            ll[i].setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                        }
                        if(alignment.equalsIgnoreCase("right")){
                            ll[i].setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                        }
                        if(alignment.equalsIgnoreCase("centre")){
                            ll[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        }
                        if(bold.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                            listText1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                        }
                        ll[i].addView(listText1);
                        ll[i].setLayoutParams(llChild);
                    }else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("spacer")){
                        llChild.width=Integer.parseInt(widthChild);
                        ll[i].setLayoutParams(llChild);
                        TextView listText1 = new TextView(context);
                        listText1.setText(" ");
                        ll[i].addView(listText1);
                    }
                }
                workkardrowLayout.addView(ll[i]);
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    //                            LinearLayout workkardrowLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    //                            workkardrowLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    //                            workkardrowLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(cardBackground));

    //if()

    //                            LinearLayout listLayoutRow1 = new LinearLayout(context);
    //                            LinearLayout listLayoutRow2 = new LinearLayout(context);
    //                            LinearLayout listLayoutRow3 = new LinearLayout(context);
    //
    //                            listLayoutRow1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    //                            listLayoutRow2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    //                            listLayoutRow3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    //
    //                            listLayoutRow1.setWeightSum(20);
    //                            listLayoutRow2.setWeightSum(20);
    //                            listLayoutRow3.setWeightSum(20);
    //
    //                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsll1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    //                            paramsll1.leftMargin = 10;
    //                            paramsll1.topMargin = 10;
    //                            paramsll1.bottomMargin = 10;
    //                            paramsll1.rightMargin = 10;
    //                            paramsll1.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
    //                            listLayoutRow1.setLayoutParams(paramsll1);
    //                            listLayoutRow2.setLayoutParams(paramsll1);
    //                            listLayoutRow3.setLayoutParams(paramsll1);
    //
    //                            TextView listText1 = new TextView(context);
    //                            listText1.setText(template);
    //                            TextView listText2 = new TextView(context);
    //                            listText2.setText("Hurre............ Dynamic lauout row2:-)");
    //                            TextView listText3 = new TextView(context);
    //                            listText3.setText("Hurre............ Dynamic lauout row 3:-)");
    //
    //                            listLayoutRow1.addView(listText1);
    //                            listLayoutRow2.addView(listText2);
    //                            listLayoutRow3.addView(listText3);
    //
    //                            workkardrowLayout.addView(listLayoutRow1);
    //                            workkardrowLayout.addView(listLayoutRow2);
    //                            workkardrowLayout.addView(listLayoutRow3);

    return workkardrowLayout;

}

String getWorkkardMethod(String fieldName){
    String work="";
    if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("template")){
        work=workkardData.getTemplate();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("workkardTitle")){
        work=workkardData.getWorkkardTitle();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("workkardDescription")){
        work=workkardData.getWorkkardDescription();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("workType")){
        work=workkardData.getWorkType();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("workkardNumber")){
        work=workkardData.getWorkkardNumber();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("claimantName")){
        work=workkardData.getClaimantName();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("reportedDate")){
        work=workkardData.getReportedDate();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("lossDate")){
        work=workkardData.getLossDate();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("lossType")){
        work=workkardData.getLossType();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("address")){
        work=workkardData.getAddress();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("county")){
        work=workkardData.getCounty();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("state")){
        work=workkardData.getState();
    }else if(fieldName.equalsIgnoreCase("zip")){
        work=workkardData.getZip();
    }

    return work;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things that you can do to improve your view's performance:

1. Reuse views(you are inflating a view for every single instance).  If you have variable number of fields then Adapter.getViewType and Adapter.getViewTypeCount are your friends.
2. FindViewById's are expensive and make for a less performant experience.  Read up on the [ViewHolder pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html).
3. If you are still running into problems you will need to look at what is causing the poor performance.  My hunch is that if you still have poor performance after doing 1 and 2 that it's that you are parsing json in your getView.  Consider preparsing your data into objects that can simply be read once getView is called.

[Supplemental](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) video(Long but very useful about adapters in general).